# Subset grouped dataset based on matches in at least 3 of 5 columns

Tags: r, subset

I am trying to subset a grouped dataset so that the code looks through each group, looks at five specific columns, sees if the rows have matching values in those columns, and if multiple rows have 3 or more matching values it will retain the first row and remove the others with 3 or more matches. NAs should not count towards that match threshold.

As an example, let's say I grouped the dataset by Month. I want the code to look through the January group, identify rows with 3 or more matches in the A, B, C, D, and E columns, and if two rows meet that threshold of matches, remove the second row. So in this case, it would remove keep remove Row 2 (since it has three matches with Row 1), while keeping all the other rows because they have <3 matches when compared head-to-head with one another.

```
data <- data.frame(
  Month = c("Jan", "Jan", "Jan", "Jan", "Feb"),
  A = c("apple", "apple", "banana", "cherry", "peach"),
  B = c("car", "car", "bike", bike", "plane"),
  C = c(NA, NA, NA, "cold", "NA"),
  D = c("London", "Paris", "Tokyo", "Tokyo", "New York"),
  E = c("earth", "earth", "wind", "fire", NA) 
)
```

So far, this has been my best attempt, but I'm pretty sure it's wrong.

```
data_cleaned <- data %>%
  group_by(`Month`) %>%
  filter(n() == 1 | (n() > 1 & row_number() == which.min(rowSums(!is.na(select(., 
                                                                              `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, `E` ))) >= 3)))
```

Comment: *I think* if you are looking for an approach working fast on a huge amount of data you should mention that. Then nobody invests time on developing an approach for a small to moderate sized data set.

Answer (score 1):

here is a `data.table` approach

```
library(data.table)
# set to data.table format
setDT(data)
# set row id's
data[, id := .I]
# cretae long dataset
data.long <- melt(data, id.vars = c("id", "Month"), na.rm = TRUE)
# create data.table with rows to compare
check.similar <- data[, id, by = Month][data[, .(id2 = id), by = Month], on = .(Month), allow.cartesian = TRUE][id < id2, ]
# columns to compare
cols <- LETTERS[1:5]
# set keys to iterate over
setkey(check.similar, id, id2)
#perform iteration
check.similar[check.similar, sameval := {
  sum(
    sapply(cols, function(x) {
      sum(data.long[id == i.id & Month == i.Month & variable == x, value] == 
        data.long[id == i.id2 & Month == i.Month & variable == x, value])
      }))
}, by = .EACHI]
# check.similar
#    Month id id2 sameval
# 1:   Jan  1   2       3
# 2:   Jan  1   3       0
# 3:   Jan  1   4       0
# 4:   Jan  2   3       0
# 5:   Jan  2   4       0
# 6:   Jan  3   4       2

# so now you can remove the rows (by month) with id == id2, where same >= 3
data[!id %in% check.similar[sameval >= 3, id2], ]
#    Month      A     B    C        D     E id
# 1:   Jan  apple   car <NA>   London earth  1
# 2:   Jan banana  bike <NA>    Tokyo  wind  3
# 3:   Jan cherry  bike cold    Tokyo  fire  4
# 4:   Feb  peach plane <NA> New York  <NA>  5
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for offering up a solution! While it does work on this small sample dataset, I do worry that it will not scale up well. While it will work well for a dataset of 1000, it may take forever to run on a dataset of 50,000+ observations. 

Do you reckon there's a way to run this to increase efficiency? Or is it simply  going to be a big ask in terms of processing no matter what?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `data.table` approach that could/should scale better

```
library(data.table)
# set to data.table format
setDT(data)
# create id
data[, id := rowid(Month)]
# melt to long
DT <- melt(data, id.vars = c("Month", "id"), na.rm = TRUE)
# self join on all rows
lookup <- DT[DT, .(Month, id = x.id, id2 = i.id, 
                  variable, value = x.value, value2 = i.value), 
            on = .(Month, variable), allow.cartesian = TRUE]
# only look down in rown, not up
lookup <- final[id < id2,]
# >=3 rows by group
rows_to_filter <- lookup[value == value2, if(.N >= 3) id2, by = .(Month, id2)]$id2
# final filtering
data[!id %in% rows_to_filter, ]

#    Month      A     B    C        D     E id
# 1:   Jan  apple   car <NA>   London earth  1
# 2:   Jan banana  bike <NA>    Tokyo  wind  3
# 3:   Jan cherry  bike cold    Tokyo  fire  4
# 4:   Feb  peach plane <NA> New York  <NA>  1
```